# Deployed version of ASP.NET Code throwing error Power Shell error

Tags: asp.net, powershell

**I have written a code to make MS Exchange ActiveSync setting enable using PowerShell. When it is deployed on Test environment everything works fine but on PROD it is throwing below error.**

ASP.NET Code

```
        string scriptFile =    HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/PSScripts/ActiveSync.ps1");
        //Create runspace
        var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();

        // create a pipeline and feed it the script text
        var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        var scriptCommand = new Command(scriptFile);

        //Add parameters
        foreach (var p in Parameters)
            scriptCommand.Parameters.Add(p);

        //Read parameters from the database

        scriptCommand.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("ActionType", ActionType));
        pipeline.Commands.Add(scriptCommand);

        //Execute
        var success = false;
        try
        {
            var results = pipeline.Invoke();
            var actualResult = Convert.ToString(results[results.Count - 1]);
            if (actualResult == "No MailBox Found")
                success = false;
            else
                success = bool.Parse(actualResult);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            success = false;
        }

        runspace.Close();
```

**PowerShell Code**

## Connect to the MSO Exchange powershell

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString $AccountPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object      System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($AccountUserName,$password)
$soption = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck


$RMsession = New-PSSession -Authentication basic -Credential $cred -   ConnectionUri exchangeURLGOESHERE -Configuration Microsoft.Exchange
Import-PSSession $RMsession -AllowClobber

 $Return = $true

 #[string[]]

 #Select action
switch ($ActionType)
{
0 {
     $Return = EnableDisableEAS -Username $Username -Email $Email -IsEnable   $IsEnable 
 }

 }

#Finish session

 Remove-PSSession $RMsession
```

I am not able to guess any issue using below exception.

**Error Detail are as below**

The type initializer for

```
System.Management.Automation.Internal.PSETWTracerFactory threw an exception.
```

StackTrace :

```
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate) 
at System.Management.Automation.PipelineNode.Execute(Array input, Pipe outputPipe, ArrayList& resultList, ExecutionContext context) 
at System.Management.Automation.ParseTreeNode.Execute(Array input, Pipe outputPipe, ExecutionContext context) 
at System.Management.Automation.AssignmentStatementNode.Execute(Array input, Pipe outputPipe, ExecutionContext context) 
at System.Management.Automation.StatementListNode.ExecuteStatement(ParseTreeNode statement, Array input, Pipe outputPipe, ArrayList& resultList, ExecutionContext context)

InnerException :

System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Management.Automation.Internal.PSETWTracerFactory' 
threw an exception. —> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for " 
threw an exception. —> .ModuleLoadException: 
The C++ module failed to load while attempting to initialize 
the default appdomain. —> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type is not 
resolved for member 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal,Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. 
at System.AppDomain.get_Id() at .DoCallBackInDefaultDomain(IntPtr function, Void* cookie) 
at .LanguageSupport.InitializeDefaultAppDomain(LanguageSupport* ) 
at .LanguageSupport._Initialize(LanguageSupport* ) 
at .LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport* ) — End of inner exception stack trace — 
at .ThrowModuleLoadException(String errorMessage, Exception innerException) 
at .LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport* ) 
at .cctor() — End of inner exception stack trace — 
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner) 
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner) 
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) 
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PSETWTracerFactory..cctor() — End of inner exception stack trace — 
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PSETWTracerFactory.GetETWTracer(PSKeyword keyword) at System.Management.Automation.RemoteRunspace..ctor(TypeTable typeTable, RunspaceConnectionInfo connectionInfo, PSHost host, PSPrimitiveDictionary applicationArguments) 
at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(RunspaceConnectionInfo connectionInfo, PSHost host, TypeTable typeTable, PSPrimitiveDictionary applicationArguments) at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSSessionCommand.CreateRunspacesWhenUriParameterSpecified() 
at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSSessionCommand.ProcessRecord() 
at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoProcessRecord() 
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
```

Comment: This issue was related to missing Microsoft.IdentityModel (WIF) on server where application was hosted. It resolved it once we installed WIF on server

Comment: If you think others can benefit from this resolution, please post it as an _answer_ (preferably with more detail), and then accept it.